# Existence of best and worst lotteries with finite outcome set and IIA

Tags: expected-utility, proof

In the context of expected utility theory, I want to prove that if the set of outcomes is finite and an agent has a rational preference relation over the set of lotteries, and if that preference relation satisfies independence of irrelevant alternatives, then there is a best and a worst lottery. This is an exercise from MWG and there is a similar question in econ SE, but I wanted to try my hand at a different proof for learning purposes.

I think I have a proof, but I am not sure it is correct. Could you tell me if I made any mistake?

Proof: the set of outcomes is finite, so complete preferences mean there is a best outcome. Therefore given outcome $\bar{R} = \max \{C\}$, $C$ being the set of outcomes, we can show that $\bar{L} = \{\bar{R} \textrm{ with probability 1}\}$ is the best lottery, by induction.

This is trivially true if $|C| = 1$ (i.e. there is only one outcome, so there is only one lottery, which is the best and worst lottery).

Now if it’s true for $|C| = n-1$:

- We can define $\bar{L}_{n-1}$ the best lottery in $C_{n-1} = C - \max\{C\}$, which yields the outcome $\bar{R}_{n-1} = \max\{C_{n-1}\}$ with probability 1.
- Let’s take now the lottery $\bar{L}$ which yields $\bar{R}$ with probability 1 and suppose there is a better lottery $\hat{L}$. This lottery must be a compound of $\bar{L}$ and $\bar{L}_{n-1}$ because $\bar{L}_{n-1}$ is preferred to any other lottery that doesn’t feature $\bar{R}$, and $\bar{L}$ already attaches probability 1 to $\bar{R}$. Moreover, $\bar{L} \succsim \bar{L}_{n-1}$ as $\bar{R} \succsim \bar{R}_{n-1}$.
- We can then denote a lottery by the probability it attaches to $\bar{R}, \bar{R}_{n-1}$, so $\bar{L} = (1, 0), \bar{L}_{n-1} = (0, 1)$.
- Suppose there exists some $\hat{L} = (p, 1-p)\succ \bar{L}$. By IIA, $t(p, 1-p) + (1-t)(0, 1) \succ t(1, 0) + (1-t)(0, 1)$. This reduces to $(tp, 1- tp) \succ (t, 1-t)$. This lottery always attaches a lower probability than $\bar{L}$ to the weakly preferred outcome $\bar{R}$, unless $p = 1$, in which case $\hat{L} = \bar{L}$, so we arrive at a contradiction as the agent is at best indifferent between $\hat{L}$ and $\bar{L}$. Thus $\bar{L}$ is the best lottery for any value of $|C|$.

The same reasoning could be applied to show that there is a worst lottery. Is this proof correct?